# Flask-SocketIO: OSError [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo, flask-socketio

The following is the error that I'm getting

OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

This error started occurring once I included MongoDB connection code in my Flask application. I suspect there might be a conflict or an issue with the socket operations.

Details:

- I am using Flask-SocketIO for real-time communication (chat application).
- My Flask application was working fine before integrating MongoDB.
- The error occurs even when MongoDB-related code is commented out.
- I am using Windows as my development environment.

This is the contents of **init**.py file in my application folder for my flask app

```
import os

from decouple import config
from flask import Flask
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.errors import ConnectionFailure

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()

socketio = SocketIO()

try:
    # setting up the mongo client
    mongo_client = MongoClient(
        host=config("MONGO_HOST"),
        port=config("MONGO_PORT", cast=int),
        username=config("MONGO_USERNAME"),
        password=config("MONGO_PASSWORD"),
    )

    chat_db = mongo_client["chat_data"]

except ConnectionFailure as e:
    raise f"Error connecting to MongoDB: {e}"


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # postgresql://username:password@host_ip:5432/database_name
    DB_URI = f"postgresql://{config('DB_USER')}:{config('DB_PASSWORD')}@{config('DB_HOST')}:{config('DB_PORT')}/{config('DB')}"
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = DB_URI
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = True

    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    from application.posts import models
    from application.users import models

    with app.app_context():
        from .chat import chat
        from .posts import posts
        from .users import users

        app.register_blueprint(users)
        app.register_blueprint(posts)
        app.register_blueprint(chat)

        # Check if the "chat_data" database exists and create it if not
        if not "chat_data" in mongo_client.list_database_names():
            chat_db = mongo_client["chat_data"]

        socketio.init_app(app)

        return app
```

To identify where the problem is coming from I tried removing the connection setup code for connecting to MongoDB, after which I found that the error is no longer popping up. This I think narrows down the root cause of the problem. But I'm not quite sure how to fix this.

Help me understand what I'm dealing with here, and any suggestions/improvements would be highly helpful.